# Using bash script to kill a process running in another terminal and closing the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, gnome

so, i have a bash script that opens a terminal and runs a java jar which keeps running until you kill it, i have another script that kills this process but the problem is that the terminal the jar was running in does not close, anyone can help me? i use linux and gnome.

*this are my scripts:*

**runRobot:**
`java -cp ~/robot-automation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar abm.robot_automation.CoordinatorV2`

**openTerminalAndRun:**
`gnome-terminal -e "bash -c ~/src/main/resources/runRobot.sh;bash"`

**killRobot:**
`pkill -f  CoordinatorV2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an `exit` to the end of the **openTerminalAndRun** script instead of the trailing bash command:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c ~/src/main/resources/runRobot.sh;exit"
```

Comment: sry for the very late reply, i voted up but never commented, it worked perfectly fyi. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It could help you `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c ~/src/main/resources/runRobot.sh;bash" && exit`